# SSL/TLS error ("no cipher suites in common") with Netty when trying to establish a secure connection between a frontend and a backend

Tags: java, ssl, netty, encryption

I want to secure a TCP connection between a backend and a frontend. We use Netty to establish a TCP connection which works pretty well. Now, we want to secure this connection by using SSL/TLS. For that reason I created a certificate request:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out request.pem -subj '/C=DE/O=XX/ST=XX/L=XX/O=XX/OU=XX/CN=someaddress.de/emailAddress=support@xxx.de'
```

The certificate was then created by the CA.

The keystore was created with:

```
keytool -import -alias xxx -keystore xxx.keystore -file cert-xxx.pem
```

Server with Netty at the backend:

```
public StatefulTcpServer(MessageHandler messageHandler, int port, KeyStore keyStore, String keyStorePassword) {
    this.messageHandler = messageHandler;
    factory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    allChannels = new DefaultChannelGroup("clients");

    initTLS(keyStore, keyStorePassword);

    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);

    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {

        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
            if (sslContext != null) {
                SSLEngine sslEngine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
                sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);
                sslEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] {
                    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
                });
                pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(sslEngine));
            }

            pipeline.addLast("compressor", new ZlibEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast("decompressor", new ZlibDecoder());

            pipeline.addLast("decoder", new JBossSerializationDecoder());
            pipeline.addLast("encoder", new JBossSerializationEncoder());

            pipeline.addLast("handler", StatefulTcpServer.this);
            return pipeline;
        }
    });

    bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);

    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
}

private void initTLS(KeyStore keyStore, String keyStorePassword) {
    try {
        if (keyStore != null) {
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
        }
    }
    catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        logger.error("TLS connection could not be established", e);
        sslContext = null;
    }
}
```

Server with Netty in the frontend:

```
public void init(String backendHost, int backendPort, int timeOutSecs, boolean useTLS,
                boolean acceptOnlyTrustworthyCertsForTLS) throws ConnectionFailedException {

    channelFactory = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

    if (useTLS) {
        initTLS(acceptOnlyTrustworthyCertsForTLS);
    }

    ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(channelFactory);
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {

        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();

            if (sslContext != null) {
                SSLEngine sslEngine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
                sslEngine.setUseClientMode(true);
                sslEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] {
                    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
                });
                pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(sslEngine));
            }

            pipeline.addLast("compressor", new ZlibEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast("decompressor", new ZlibDecoder());

            pipeline.addLast("decoder", new JBossSerializationDecoder());
            pipeline.addLast("encoder", new JBossSerializationEncoder());

            pipeline.addLast("handler", StatefulTcpBackendCommunicator.this);
            return pipeline;
        }
    });
    bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("keepAlive", true);

    channelFuture = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(backendHost, backendPort));
    try {
        boolean connected = channelFuture.await(timeOutSecs * 1000);
        if (!connected || !channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
            throw new ConnectionFailedException();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}


private void initTLS(boolean acceptOnlyTrustworthyCertsForTLS) {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustManagers;
        if (acceptOnlyTrustworthyCertsForTLS) {
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory
                            .getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
            trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        }
        else {
            trustManagers = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {

                    @Override
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        return;
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
    }
    catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        logger.error("TLS connection could not be established. TLS is not used!", e);
        sslContext = null;
    }
}
```

When trying to establish the connection between frontend and backend I get an exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662837/java-no-cipher-suites-in-common-issue-when-trying-to-securely-connect-to-serve) was unfortunately not helpful. Is there something wrong with the configuration of the servers? Or do I use the wrong certificate type?

Comment: Have you tried switching out the cipher suites on both the server and front-end? Maybe it's something with that specific cipher.

Comment: you might also monitor the connection with WireShark to see if either side is actually behaving like you expect.

Comment: It works if I allow cipher suites without authentification. Any ideas? Using the Eclipse debuggerl, the initialization of the SSLContext in the backend seems to be working.

Comment: I finally found the problem: the private key was missing in the keystore.