# No cipher suites in common Netty

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, netty, mutual-authentication

I've been trying to do mutual authentication with Netty on Java between my server and a client.

I have already generated the certificates with java keytool by following several examples. I tried to manually set the cipher suites in both the client and the server. The only way i can get my code working is if I turn client authentication off.

The ssl debug output is not giving me any conclusive information. It would help me greatly if someone can give me some pointers in order to solve my problem.

Client code:

```
@Override public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    String password = "blablabla";

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    InputStream readStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("clientCert.jks");
    ks.load(readStream,
            password.toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory
            .getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmFactory.init(ks);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

    SSLEngine sslEngine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
    sslEngine.setUseClientMode(true);

    sslEngine.setEnabledProtocols(sslEngine.getSupportedProtocols());
    sslEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"});
    sslEngine.setEnableSessionCreation(true);

    pipeline.addFirst("SSL", new SslHandler(sslEngine));

    pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufDecoder(Messaging.BaseMessage.getDefaultInstance()));
    pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
    pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufEncoder());

    // and then business logic.
    pipeline.addLast(new ServerHandlerCorrelator());
}
```

Server code:

```
@Override public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    String password = "blablabla";

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    // Use nettyserver.jks do client side authentication
    InputStream readStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("serverCert.jks");
    ks.load(readStream,
            password.toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory
            .getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmFactory.init(ks);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

    SSLEngine sslEngine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
    sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);
    sslEngine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
    sslEngine.setEnabledProtocols(sslEngine.getSupportedProtocols());
    sslEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"});
    sslEngine.setEnableSessionCreation(true);

    // Add SSL handler into pipeline
    pipeline.addFirst("SSL", new SslHandler(sslEngine));

    // Add protobuf handler into pipeline
    pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufDecoder(Messaging.BaseMessage.getDefaultInstance()));
    pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
    pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufEncoder());

    // Add custom handler
    pipeline.addLast(new ServerHandler());
}
```

Server SSL Log:

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1479318961 bytes = { 32, 234, 91, 96, 106, 19, 244, 166, 143, 174, 72, 157, 75, 108, 113, 168, 230, 206, 9, 133, 102, 255,     246, 237, 100, 250, 62, 211 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA,     SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 84
0000: 01 00 00 50 03 03 58 2D   9E B1 20 EA 5B 60 6A 13  ...P..X-.. .[`j.
0010: F4 A6 8F AE 48 9D 4B 6C   71 A8 E6 CE 09 85 66 FF  ....H.Klq.....f.
0020: F6 ED 64 FA 3E D3 00 00   02 00 2F 01 00 00 25 00  ..d.>...../...%.
0030: 0D 00 1C 00 1A 06 03 06   01 05 03 05 01 04 03 04  ................
0040: 01 04 02 03 03 03 01 03   02 02 03 02 01 02 02 FF  ................
0050: 01 00 01 00                                        ....
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 84
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 47
0000: 01 03 03 00 06 00 00 00   20 00 00 2F 00 00 FF 58  ........ ../...X
0010: 2D 9E B1 20 EA 5B 60 6A   13 F4 A6 8F AE 48 9D 4B  -.. .[`j.....H.K
0020: 6C 71 A8 E6 CE 09 85 66   FF F6 ED 64 FA 3E D3     lq.....f...d.>.
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 47
[Raw write]: length = 49
0000: 80 2F 01 03 03 00 06 00   00 00 20 00 00 2F 00 00  ./........ ../..
0010: FF 58 2D 9E B1 20 EA 5B   60 6A 13 F4 A6 8F AE 48  .X-.. .[`j.....H
0020: 9D 4B 6C 71 A8 E6 CE 09   85 66 FF F6 ED 64 FA 3E  .Klq.....f...d.>
0030: D3                                                 .
6539 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG one.ppdrforensics.server.comms.ServerHandlerCorrelator  - NETTY Connected to Correlator
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, called closeOutbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, closeOutboundInternal()
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, called closeInbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, fatal error: 80: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, Exception sending alert: java.io.IOException: writer side was already closed.
```

Client SSL Log:

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 80 2F 01 03 03                                     ./...
[Raw read]: length = 44
0000: 00 06 00 00 00 20 00 00   2F 00 00 FF 58 2D 9E B1  ..... ../...X-..
0010: 20 EA 5B 60 6A 13 F4 A6   8F AE 48 9D 4B 6C 71 A8   .[`j.....H.Klq.
0020: E6 CE 09 85 66 FF F6 ED   64 FA 3E D3              ....f...d.>.
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 3
0000: 01 03 03                                           ...
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 44
0000: 00 06 00 00 00 20 00 00   2F 00 00 FF 58 2D 9E B1  ..... ../...X-..
0010: 20 EA 5B 60 6A 13 F4 A6   8F AE 48 9D 4B 6C 71 A8   .[`j.....H.Klq.
0020: E6 CE 09 85 66 FF F6 ED   64 FA 3E D3              ....f...d.>.
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ:  SSL v2, contentType = Handshake, translated length = 47
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1479318961 bytes = { 32, 234, 91, 96, 106, 19, 244, 166, 143, 174, 72, 157, 75, 108, 113, 168, 230, 206, 9, 133, 102, 255,     246, 237, 100, 250, 62, 211 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, called closeOutbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, closeOutboundInternal()
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, called closeInbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify:     possible truncation attack?
0    [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] ERROR one.ppdrforensics.correlator.comms.ServerHandler  - [exceptionCaught] Exception     javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, called closeOutbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, closeOutboundInternal()
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, called closeInbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, closeInboundInternal()
```

Comment: Your main problem is `no cipher suites in common`. What client and server software / Java version do you use?

Comment: I have been trying to run both the client and the server on the same machine. Java is 1.8_102 and Netty is 4.1.4 final.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please debug using -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:all parameter enable? It will give more information about SSLhandshake. Please look for type of client and server certificate. Are they DSA or RSA certificate?
[Java "no cipher suites in common" issue when trying to securely connect to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662837/java-no-cipher-suites-in-common-issue-when-trying-to-securely-connect-to-serve?rq=1)

Comment: The two last pieces of code i posted are the logs using the -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:all parameter. I generated the certificates using RSA.